# how to deselect Image View when clicked on another item in adapter

Tags: java, android, view, imageview, android-adapter

I have `RecyclerView` with one text view and one custom made `CheckBoxView` class which is clickable and has focus as well which is instantiated in adapter. All the logic is in this class.

Now when single row has focus,  Checkbox is yellow, and when clicked is gray. The problem goes when I click on another item because the previously clicked item which is saved to gray doesn't go to Empty image, but stayed in previously state.

It should go empty when another CheckBox is clicked.

```
public class MyCheckBoxView {

public enum CheckType {
    ACTIVE, // YELLOW When check box has focus on 
    SELECTED, // GRAY When user selects view
    EMPTY // // EMPTY When not selected

}

private CheckType checkType;
private ImageView view;
private boolean isChecked = false;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public MyCheckBoxView() {
    setup();
}

//Setup method: Fill In View
private void setup() {
    //Create view
    view = new ImageView(getContext());
    view.setFocusable(true);
    view.setClickable(true);

    setCheckType(CheckType.EMPTY);
    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_box_empty);

    //Set CheckBox focus behaviours
    view.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                checkType = CheckType.ACTIVE;
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_box_active);
            } else {
                // NO FOCUS
                view.setImageResource(R.drawaable.check_box_empty);

                // If checkbox view is checked
                if (isChecked) {
                    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_box_selected);
                    checkType = CheckType.SELECTED;
                } else {
                    if (checkType == CheckType.SELECTED) {
                        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_box_selected);
                        isChecked = true;
                    } else {
                        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_box_empty);
                        isChecked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //Set CheckBox state on click event
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isChecked) {
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_box_selected);
                checkType = CheckType.SELECTED;
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
}

//GET VIEW - Called in Adapter
public View getView() {
    return view;
}

//Set Check Type
public void setCheckType(CheckType checkType) {
    this.checkType = checkType;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do something like this
When some checkbox is checked remove gray from every checkbox and then apply gray to the clicked checkbox
When you will check it you will get the id of the clicked and checked checkbox and you can set it to gray through `setOnClickListener`!
Make sure to add

```
 view.setImageResource(R.drawable.beeline_check_box_selected);
            checkType = CheckType.SELECTED;
```

after you remove all gray!